# Is there a web application to create a timeline of events?

Tags: wiki

My country is going through difficult times. I want to create a mostly graphical timeline of events in a wiki like fashion. I want everyone who wants to get involved to contribute and comment. What is my best option?

Answer (score 2):

You can use timeline.js. The data back end can be a google spreadsheet. This is an open source project so at any point when you have someone to help you out with development you can do that to.

http://timeline.verite.co/

and on github https://github.com/VeriteCo/TimelineJS

Answer (score 1):

[Timeglider](http://timeglider.com/) is a free web-based application that allows you to create timelines with the option to collaborate (though I don't know that it's as open as a wiki, per se). [Dipity](http://www.dipity.com/) is another similar application with collaboration as an option.

StudyVibe also has a listing of several [Timeline Creation Tools](http://www.studyvibe.com.au/Really-cool-sites/Timeline-Creation-Tools.aspx).

Comment: @niw3 Sure thing. If you found the answer helpful you can up-vote and/or accept it see [WebApps About](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/about).

Comment: I am trying them one by one. So far, no wiki-like editing. None of them seems to be suitable for events in progress that are minutes or hours apart. Unfortunately I am not a web developer, so I can't start such a project. But I believe I can contribute.

Answer (score 0):

I think [proofhub](http://www.proofhub.com) is a free web based application that can help you. It has features like time tracking, assigning a task to multiple users, to-do's, discussions and many more. I hope you will like this tool and find it useful for your work.

Comment: If you are affiliated with the product, please disclose this in your answer.